# Program for quick, drag and drop file and url sharing

Tags: drag-and-drop

It's common that myself or a colleague will need to send a web page or small file (ie font file) to one another which is usually done by emailing it, but this just seems a bit of a waste of time.

I have dropbox and this makes sense for use with large files, but for things like urls, I want to be able to drag the webpage or url onto an icon for my colleagues computer and it pops up onto their screen as an alert. Does something like this exist?

We have a mix of mac and pc so something cross browser would be ideal, but if there's a mac only solution I'll be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google talk](http://www.google.com/talk/) or another free IM program should work.  GT works with both Mac and PC/Windows and supports drag/drop file sharing and cutting/pasting urls to make links.  If you use gmail the chat history is also saved in your gmail account which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a try with Skype...